# Find the hash in the text

Tags: code-golf, string

I hate hashes because they remind me of hashtags, help me find them in the input

## Input

A piece of text

```
This is an #example text,
#designed for demo #purposes,
#to demonstrate the challenge.#
```

- You may add a optional newline character at the end of the input if your program requires this
- You may assume that there will be no input longer than 100 lines
- You may freely assume there will be no line longer than 100 characters
- You should assume the input doesn't contain any trailing spaces
- You may alternatively take the input as a list of lines

## Challenge

Surround every hash symbol with an hit article, to help me find it

```
  |
--#--
  |
```

- If the hash symbol on the first line, you need to add more lines to the top of the grid
- If the hash symbol is too far to the left, you need to prefix all lines with spaces to make place for the left side of the hitmarker
- If the hash symbol if too far to the bottom of the text, add more lines
- If an hitmarker of another hash symbol overwrites the hitmarker of the first hash symbol, it doesn't matter what one wins (see example 5)
- An hitmarker may not overwrite any other hash symbol, but should overwrite the text

## Output

Another piece of text, that has the hit markers on the correct place

```
             |
  |his is a--#--ample|text,
--#--signed f|r dem--#--rposes, |
--#-- demonstrate the|challeng--#--
  |                             |
```

- You should treat the input as a "matrix" of characters, and you should only extend this "matrix" in the directions required if the hitmarker doesn't fit the grid (so a hash symbol in line 0 means extending the grid to line -1, a hash symbol in column 0 means extending it to columns -2, etc...)
- When you output the matrix, you should strip any trailing spaces
- The output may contain a trailing newline, as long as that line is empty (this is to accomplish for launches that only have a `print_and_output_newline` function)

## Test cases

1: In:

```
a
```

1: Output:

```
a
```

---

2: In:

```
#
```

2: Out:

```
  |
--#--
  |
```

---

3: In:

```
#a
aa
```

3: Out:

```
  |
--#--
  |a
```

---

4: In:

```
aa
a#
```

4: Out:

```
 a|
--#--
  |
```

---

5: In:

```
###
#a#
```

5: Out:

```
  |||
--###--
--#-#--
  | |
```

5: Or:

```
  |||
--###--
--#|#--
  | |
```

---

6: In:

```
a
a
#
a
a
```

6: Out:

```
  a
  |
--#--
  |
  a
```